# Quick introduction to electromagnetism / Maxwell's equations

Tags: electromagnetism, soft-question, education, resource-recommendations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Electrodynamics textbook that emphasizes applications](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20752/electrodynamics-textbook-that-emphasizes-applications)

I am a graduate student in applied mathematics and I am looking for a concise introduction to [Maxwell's equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) / basic principles of [electromagnetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetism). (I have enjoyed the book by Purcell, *Electricity and Magnetism,* as an undergrad but I have forgotten most of it). I would like something that covers the conceptual details in a quick way and not necessarily a big textbook. You may assume that I have the necessary mathematics background. I am looking for something that will explain the physics, i.e not a huge textbook with intricate calculations but a short book to get a feel for what is going on.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20752/2451

Comment: I think this is close enough to be considered a duplicate.

Comment: @Shibi: I think you'll find what you're looking for in Jackson's grad text; skim the chapters on statics, then read the chapter on Time Varying Fields, Maxwell's Equations, and conserved charges.  It's fairly easy reading (the challenge in Jackson is the problems).

Comment: Griffiths is decent : http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Electrodynamics-Edition-David-Griffiths/dp/0321856562 for fundamentals and a somewhat historical treatment.  If you are a math student there are more fundamental treatments (Lorenz and Coulomb gauges, and even a differential forms derivation).  I have a masters in math and I wish that I had learned E&M in one of these more fundamental forms (Gauge or differential forms).

Answer (score 1):

One book I always recommend for learning Maxwell's equations is this book by [Daniel Fleish: A Student's Guide to Maxwell's Equations.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521701473) It may perhaps be, at times, a little bit easy (given your mathematics background), but in general, I really think you'll enjoy this book (and, judging from the reviews on Amazon, most people do). It's not huge (144 pages) and very accessible.