# Where can I learn about Motors and Generators?

Tags: electromagnetism, applied-physics

[image]

[image]

[image: enter preformatted text here]`

Where can I learn about the functionality of motors and generators, so I can answer questions such as these? I need a good textbook that starts from the basics (eg faradays) then moves up with lots of questions.

Can I also know if this is hard to pick up?

Comment: Relevant: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20752/