# Any good electricity and magnetism books for highschool students?

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, education, classical-electrodynamics

I really want to learn about electricity and magnetism for a long time but never have gotten to it, are there are good books that are conceptual on the topic of electromagnetism? I do not know calculus btw.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electrodynamics textbooks that emphasize applications](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20752/)

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour] (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 4) If you get a satisfactory answer, remember to accept it by clicking on the green checkmark.

Comment: Electromagnetism is not an easy subject to approach without calculus. Even the most basic concepts require at least some background in multivariable. An easy place to start might be basic circuit theory, since you'll encounter some principles of electrodynamics in a very self-consistent formalism. I'd personally recommend trying to learn some calculus, and working through something like Feynman (Vol. 2) as a way of motivating your work.

Comment: There are dozens of good books. Why not ask your teacher about them? Or take a look in your school library? Presumably you are thinking of studying on your own.  That requires a lot of self-discipline and self-motivation.  Asking others to tell you what to study, rather than using whatever resources are available to you, is not an auspicious start.

Answer (score 1):

Google **mathematical methods in the physical sciences pdf** and you will be able to download an ebook by Mary Boas, which was written for people like yourself. As Jacob says above, calculus is a must learn, and lots of websites give you examples of different levels of calculus problems.

Conceptually, a good textbook is Halliday and Resnicks Physics, which sets out the physics behind electricity and magnetism in a straightforward way and also goes through some of the basic calculus needed.

Best of luck with it