# Magnetic Flux Density inside a Solenoid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

What will be the net magnetic induction inside a solenoid with iron core and the solenoid in a medium ( say oil ) in terms of magnetic intensity and intensity of magnetization .

I know that magnetic intensity is independent of the intervening medium and and iron core would affect the intensity of magnetisation greatly but what would be the effect of oil in the situation .

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that you are expected to have thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question. You can consider checking the [advice on writing good questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have added the previous knowledge that I had . Now can you help me ?

Comment: The effect of the oil, as well as of other details of the design are taken into account by means of an [effective permeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid#Quantitative_description) $\mu_\text{eff}$, but I anticipate the effect will be small. For the basics of electromagnetism, there are many sources on-line, like [hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/elemag.html#c5), or in print: check our book recommendations [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142419/75633) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20752/75633).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the the [relative permeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)) of the oil that you are using. I would guess that $\mu_\mathrm r \approx 1$, so it does not really enhance or suppress the magnetic field.